# Can't see any link button next to a question

Tags: discussion, badges, publicity-badges, participation

I was just reading about the Announce, Booster and Publicist badges and only today did I learn about them. Out of curiosity I went to look for the link button on a question but I can't see any. Do we need some minimum reputation to see the link button? I have 700 reputation. Or perhaps something changed?

[image]

Comment: It has been renamed `share`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Which seems foolish to me, until recently I assumed that was only for those silly twitter, facebook etc links

Comment: Thank you.. Please give an answer and I will accept it..

Comment: @Richard You Sir, are very true.. Same I used to think..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just below your freehand circle, is a link called `share`.

[image: share link]

Right there where there is another freehand circle. Recursion!

Click on it and see this:

[image: opened share window]

Now you can copy that link. **Or** just right-click on the `share` link, and select 'Copy Link Address` from the context menu.

<sub><sup>(don't mind the `timeline` and `history` entries, those are added by a user script: [SE Modifications -- Username autocomplete in comments, inline revision source, and utility links](https://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a))</sup></sub>

Comment: Woah, a number of buttons you are privileged to.. What are timeline and history by the way if you dont mind..

Comment: @Akshat: Those are added by an extension.

Comment: @Akshat: added a link to the link adding.. script

Comment: Extension in the sense.? Aren't those because of your 50K repo.?

Comment: Okay.. Got it..

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Share` button instead.

[image: Share]